# Importing a Semibold font to QML

Tags: qt, text, fonts, qml, qt5

I am trying to import a Semibold font, in particular, the [Montserrat Semibold variant](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat) to QML. In order to do so, I'm using the following code:

```
FontLoader{
    id: semi
    source: "Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf"
}
```

Where `Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf` is the following file:

[image]

And then I try to visualize it on screen with the `Text` type:

```
Text{
   text: Math.round(100*progress.value) + "%"
   anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
   font.pixelSize: qmlCfg.fontSize
   color: "black"
   font.family: semi.name
   font.bold: true
}
```

The problem is that the text appears to be bold, and not semibold, as I was expecting:

[image]

As you can see, this 35% looks more bold than semibold to me:

[image]

Do you know how to fix this? If I set `font.bold: false`, the text changes to the regular variant, which is not what I want either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your font is properly loaded? For me this example gives the correct output as shown in the screenshot.

Besides the `font.bold` property there is also `font.weight` on which you can set the weight of semi bold (`600`), but as you can see in my example it doesn't have an impact on the text as the font only includes one font weight which is semi bold (`600`). This you can also see in the console output added to the `FontLoader`.

**Output**

```
qml: Font weight 600
```

**Example**

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    title: "Font"
    width: 1000
    height: 240
    visible: true

    FontLoader {
        id: webFont
        source: "qrc:/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf"

        Component.onCompleted: console.log("Font weight", webFont.font.weight)
    }

    component TestText: Text {
        text: "Whereas recognition of the inherent dignity"
        font.family: webFont.font.family
        font.pixelSize: 48
    }

    Column {
        TestText {}
        TestText { font.weight: 600 }
        TestText { font.bold: true }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

```
.
├── assets.qrc
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── main.qml
└── Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf
```

**assets.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
...
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

qt_add_executable(appuntitledStackoverflow
    assets.qrc
    main.cpp
)
...
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like the font is not properly loaded on the Qt simulator. How can I fix this?

Comment: I've used the [Qt Resource Collection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html#qt-resource-collection-file-qrc) to make the *.ttf available in the project. And with the path `"qrc:/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf"` set it as the source of the `FontLoader`.